# How do I make a dump of a MS SQL database using SQuirreL SQL?

Tags: database, ms-sql

Unfortunately I cannot use Microsoft's database tool to access my MS SQL server, so I need to use another tool like SQuirreL SQL.

How can I make a backup (i.e. dump) of the database?